# Some elements take too long to be identified when playing your coded UI test

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, automated-tests, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

Let's say I have an automated test case that launches Google.com and searches for a string.

- Launch google.com
- Search "Malaysian Airline"

I have all the necessary properties for search field identified so that playback can find this very easy and run through it. But, when I run the test, it takes up to 10-14 seconds only to find the search field in Google.com and then searching in it.

My Code is

```
BrowserWindow browser = BrowserWindow.Launch("www.google.com");
            UITestControl UISearch = new UITestControl(browser);
            UISearch.TechnologyName = "Web";
            UISearch.SearchProperties.Add("ControlType", "Edit");
            UISearch.SearchProperties.Add("Id", "lst-ib");
            Mouse.Click(UISearch);
            Keyboard.SendKeys(UISearch, "Malaysian Airline");
```

You guys could also try it out. There are next to nothing else on Google.com still it takes too long to find the element where I have already given possible and the only unique Id.

Comment: Notice that the search box on google.com is not located directly under the main window, but there are about 5-6 controls wrapping it. 
try adding the parent contrl and perhaps another one in between. 
that wat the recorder won't have to go through all of them - which is time consuming and instead locate the search box directly.

Comment: So no good solution to address the search field directly without going through so many control layers ?

Comment: not excatly - to adress the search field codedui first must find it and that's the time consuming task. you can help him with this task by supplying a more accurate controls hierarchy.

Comment: Long means how much time does it take ? more than 10 sec ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid robots Google uses a dynamic container that changes/wraps the position of search filed hence your script that once worked won't work again.

The idea is then to write the test code with full deeper path. i.e. dont just put the xpath to search text filed but also to the Div and container it belongs.

Answer (score 0):

Using [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/) on firefox it's 10 seconds where \n pressed enter and avoiding the cost of hovering and clicking on the element.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{
    FirefoxDriver firefox;

    // This is the test to be carried out.
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        firefox = new FirefoxDriver();
        firefox.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com/");
        IWebElement element = firefox.FindElement(By.Id("lst-ib"));
        element.SendKeys("Google\n");
    }

    // This closes the driver down after the test has finished.
    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
        firefox.Quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: 10 seconds is still pretty long time don't you think. There has to be some way of scanning through the control layers!

Comment: I don't  think it's that long. You need to remember that time includes launching the browser, navigating and loading the webpage too. So the actual test logic could be < 3 seconds.

Comment: That's correct Jamie Rees, if you want to run multiple iterations then open a new question and we can address the time you can save using the same browser window already logged in.

Comment: Browser and site gets ready in less than 5 seconds. Then Google page stays still for like 9 seconds.. before it starts search. Reason is, the google search box is in some parent categories or containers deep that just giving the properties of element isn't enough.

Comment: @Firaun How did you determine this is the reason?

Comment: @lloydm When I recorded this test with CodedUI record function, then the entire test took 4 seconds. The difference I saw was;

With Manaul coding: I had just given properties of search field like any other normal web element. Playback took time because it could not find the relevant element within damn many parents layers

Recorded: With recorded test, I saw that it had mapped all the parent and layers called and selected for the search element. so when you run the test, the system didn't have to look for element that much since it was very speicifically identified.

Comment: @Firaun So you want to optimize your code? or convert the Recorded coded outside of the uimap?

Comment: i was looking for an option to find the element quicker but still avoiding going through all the containers and subcontainers to point to one element.